# 4-Way Switch Problem

Tags: wiring

I purchased several hundred dollars worth of Legrand Radiant electrical outlets and switches in Graphite color for my home. All went well until I ran into a 4-way circuit (One light, two 3-way switches, and one 4-way switch). Problem is that Legrand doesn’t make a Graphite 4-way switch in their Radiant product line. Aside from installing a mis-matched color 4-way switch, are there any wiring alternatives to get around this problem? One option I considered and that I could easily agree to, is to eliminate the last 3-way switch and just install a color matched (but non-functioning) switch as we never use that switch for the light anyway. Is that possible? Are there any other working alternatives, possibly a dimmer in place of the 4-way?

Comment: Where are the switches located? It may be the case that all three switches are required by Code.

Comment: In the eat-in kitchen. One switch is adjacent to patio door, second is located in kitchen, third is in the eat-in kitchen. Each switch is no more than 10 feet from the chandelier light over the table. I never use the switch adjacent to the patio door.

Comment: Legrand offers a color switchable cover for their dimmers, I actually purchased one for a dimmer in the dining room because they didn’t have enough dimmers in graphite.

Comment: Which switch does Legrand specify for use in the 4-way position? Smart switches don't follow the same rules as trad. wiring and I would expect you'd use another 3-way remote in the 4-way positions, but check their docs.

Answer (score 1):

Leviton offers a color change kit for their switches. Legrand may offer the same, **or** you may simply be able to take a Graphite 3-way and a White (or other color) 4-way and pop the Graphite plastic cover off the 3-way and put it on the 4-way. It gets back to the "too many SKUs" problem I keep encountering - they don't sell enough 4-ways to justify producing/stocking 4-way versions of every color, but the mechanical/electronic parts are the same for all colors, so just *switch the colorful parts*.